# Can Ice Knife hit a target under the effect of Mirror Image and destroy its illusions?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123886/is-this-the-correct-way-to-resolve-a-missed-ice-knife/150431?noredirect=1#comment387668_150431) it was explained that the blast of the knife reaches a 2x2 area.

As the description of the spell *Mirror Image* makes mention of 4 targets next to each other, could it hit the actual target and make the illusions disappear?

Comment: Hey, @Rodrick! Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Comment: Welcome to the site and please take our [tour]! Just as an aside, please note that the question you linked to utilizes some house-rules.

Comment: If you don't think that linked question is a duplicate, please let us know. If you can clarify that your question is different, we can work to update your question and get this reopened.

Comment: The question is of the effect of magic on illusions. it's not a replica

Comment: Given that Ice Knife has both a component with an attack roll and a secondary effect AOE (with save), this may be out of the scope of the question that's been linked as a duplicate.